# array.slice() not functioning if I have it start from anything but 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, pagination

I have a list of 8 objects in an array called `$scope.results`, I also have a `selectAll()` function that I am currently trying to make work with my custom simple pagination.

***Please do not comment saying I should use bootstrap pagination for angularjs, I made my own and it does what I need it to do.***

```
$scope.results = [
      {
        "devID": "1",
        "devName": "item 1",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "2",
        "devName": "item 2",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "3",
        "devName": "item 3",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "4",
        "devName": "item 4",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "5",
        "devName": "item 5",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "6",
        "devName": "item 6",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "7",
        "devName": "item 7",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      },
      {
        "devID": "8",
        "devName": "item 8",
        "desc": "sample desc"
      }
    ];
```

I have an empty object called `$scope.deleteList = {}` which `selectAll()` fills with ID's.

This is my `$scope.selectAll()` (with added console logs for me to see whats happening):

```
    $scope.selectAll = function(){


        $scope.resultsToDelete = $scope.results.slice(($scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize), $scope.pageSize);
        console.log("$scope.results:", $scope.results);
        console.log("$scope.currentPage:", $scope.currentPage);
        console.log("$scope.pageSize:", $scope.pageSize);
        console.log("$scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize:", ($scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize));


        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.resultsToDelete.length; i++) {
            var item = $scope.resultsToDelete[i]; 
            $scope.devDelList[item.devID] = true;
        }



    };
```

`($scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize)` gives me the index of the first object on the next page of my list.

And this is my pagination:

```
    $scope.pagination = function(itemList) {
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        $scope.pageSize = 4;
        $scope.numOfPages = Math.ceil(itemList.length / $scope.pageSize);
        $scope.pageNumbersArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.numOfPages -1 ; i++) {
            $scope.pageNumbersArray.push(i);
        }
    }($scope.results)



$scope.prev = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
        $scope.currentPage = -- $scope.currentPage;
    }
}

$scope.next = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.numOfPages - 1 ) {
        $scope.currentPage = ++ $scope.currentPage;
    }
}

$scope.goToPage = function(pageNum) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNum;
}
```

My issue is with the `.slice()` on the results array. It works fine for the first page only - when `$scope.currentPage = 0`. As soon as `$scope.currentPage = 1`, $scope.results.slice() returns an empty array.

$scope.results.slice(0, 4) returns the correct IDs for the first page of 4 items.

$scope.results.slice(4, 4) returns an empty array. (e.g. []), it does not return the second set of 4 items

What am I missing?

Comment: *"Please do not comment saying I should use bootstrap pagination for angularjs, I made my own and it does what I need it to do."* That kind of thing is not useful, and probably makes people walk away from the question without bothering to read further and answer it.

Comment: I disagree, it is useful to me because I know people will digress and not actually answer my question, but rather go on about how I can do other things better, which I don't need right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $scope.results.slice(4, 4) returns an empty array. (e.g. [])

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> Zero-based index before which to end extraction. slice extracts up to
>   but not including end.
>
> For example, slice(1,4) extracts the second element through the fourth
>   element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3).

So, from **4** to **4** should be **0** only.

You need to try

```
var startIndex = $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize;
var endIndex = ($scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize) + $scope.pageSize;
$scope.resultsToDelete = $scope.results.slice( startIndex, endIndex );
```

Comment: This is exactly it, I had misunderstood what the .slice(start, end) means. I interpreted it as "end after 4 items"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [slice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

The seconds argument is not the length, but it is the end index.

Say you have an array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

If you wanted to select `[3,4]`

Then you would have to tun slice with `slice(2,4)` and not `slice(2,2)`

You should fix your code to be something like:

```
res = $scope.results.slice(($scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize),
    $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize + $scope.pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

`anArray.slice(n, n)` will always return an empty array.
The arguments for `slice` are `(begin, end)` where `begin` is the start index and the `end` is the end index, not the length for the slice.

In your case you would want something like this:

```
var start = $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize;
var end = start + $scope.pageSize;

$scope.resultsToDelete = $scope.results.slice( start, end );
```

Answer (score 1):

its because **The Slice method works on zero based Index** [See documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).

so, for `array.slice(begin,end);`

> begin : Zero-based index at which to begin extraction.
>
> end :  Zero-based index before which to end extraction. slice
>   extracts up to but not including end.

so for eg.

```
var arr  = [1,2,3,4];
```

when we say `arr.slice(1,3);` it means get all elements starting from index 1 to index 4 also exclude value at index 4 so `result is [2,3]`

and **when we say `arr.slice(1,1);` its like get all element from index 1 to index 1 also exclude value at index 1 so result is `[]` `empty array`**